# Making a query of how many times a photo has been included to an album

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm stuck with this. I have 2 models, `photo` and `album`.
It is a many to many relationship, with an intermediate table called `photo_listings`that has `photo_id`and `album_id` columns

The thing is, I would like to have a counter in my views, on **how many times a photo has been added to an album (All of the albums, not one in particular).**

For that, I suppose Ill need to create a method/scope `album_count`, so I can do `photo.album_count` in my views.

Inside that method, I'm doing:

```
def album_count
   Photo_listing.includes(:photo_id).count
end
```

I don't know how to generate that query. I read Active Record documentation but can't find it either. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this [video of `counter_cache`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column?view=comments) and implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `photo` is in many-to-many relationship with `album`, then it means from `album` you can use

```
photo.albums
```

to access the relationship. Therefore

```
def albums_count
  photo.albums.count
end
```

You don't need to reference the intermediate table/model, unless you have to.

If you want to count all the times a photo was added to an album, then (assuming you used `has_many :through`)

```
class Photo
  def total_albums_count
    PhotoListing.where(photo_id: id).count
  end    
end
```

Comment: WTH! I didn't realize that. It was so simple as doing photo.albums.count ... Thanks Simeone!